# In groovy, how can i iterate over a csv file and call a function for every "group" that as a different value on some of the columns?

Tags: csv, jenkins, groovy, functional-programming, jenkins-groovy

In Groovy and running on a jenkins pipeline, I am using the readFile function from jenkins to read the csv file.

Example csv:

| name | val1 | val2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 2 | 122 |
| John | 2 | 012 |
| Bertha | 2 | 0021 |
| John | 3 | 20 |
| Philip | 3 | 12022 |
| Bertha | 3 | 162021 |
| John | 3 | 2022 |

What I am trying to achieve is call another function for each different value in column "name".

The Groovy script flow would be something like:

- call functionX (name, rest of values) with:

| name | val1 | val2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 2 | 122 |
| John | 2 | 012 |
| John | 3 | 20 |
| John | 3 | 2022 |

- then call functionX (name, rest of values) with:

| name | val1 | val2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Philip | 3 | 12022 |

- then call functionX (name, rest of values) with:

| name | val1 | val2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bertha | 2 | 0021 |
| Bertha | 3 | 162021 |

**Note:**
The order (John, Philip, Bertha) is not important!

I think i can achieve this with closures but I'm not quite sure since I'm pretty new to the topic

Comment: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/CharSequence.html#splitEachLine(java.lang.CharSequence,%20groovy.lang.Closure)

Comment: im not that good :/

Comment: Does it need to group all of the same-name items together. or can it call them as they occur by line (John1, John2, Bertha1, John3, Philip1, etc.)?

Comment: Did you see my answer? I hope it works for you. If this solution works and no other answers are given, it's customary for the asker to select it as the best answer. If you LIKE the solution, it is customary to upvote it also. But more important **to the community** than the "correct" and "upvote" points is knowing whether or not this solved your problem. Please let us know. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Is this something like what you are looking for?

```
def functionX(name,val1,val2) {
    if (name == 'name') return
    println ( "Name: $name, V1: $val1, V2: $val2" )
}

new File( 'names.csv' ).readLines().sort{ it }.each {
    println it
    functionX( *( it.split( ',' ) ) )
}
```

Output:

```
Bertha,2,21
Name: Bertha, V1: 2, V2: 21
Bertha,3,162021
Name: Bertha, V1: 3, V2: 162021
John,2,12
Name: John, V1: 2, V2: 12
John,2,122
Name: John, V1: 2, V2: 122
John,3,20
Name: John, V1: 3, V2: 20
John,3,2022
Name: John, V1: 3, V2: 2022
Philip,3,12022
Name: Philip, V1: 3, V2: 12022
name,val1,val2
```